# Hardening /home Directory via /etc/fstab

Tags: linux, fstab

I am on Ubunto 20.04 server using a single partition at / for all directories as I am running web & mail servers.  I hardened `tmp` , `/var/tmp` , & `/run/shm` using:

```
none /tmp       tmpfs nodev,noexec,nosuid 0 0
none /var/tmp   tmpfs nodev,noexec,nosuid 0 0
none /run/shm   tmpfs noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
```

I would like to add the `nodev` option to my /home directory without creating a whole new partition.  I've added:
`none /home   ext4   nodev        0 0` to `/etc/fstab`

However, when I run `mount -a` for the config to effect, I get the following message:
`mount: /home: special device none does not exist.`

Is this the expected output given my config or have done something fatally wrong?  If someone can share a correct method to `nodev` to `/home`, I'd appreciate it.

thanks

**Goal**
I want to prevent the /home directory from being used for
defining character and block special devices. Therefore, I want to set the nodev option, so that users cannot create these types of files.

Comment: I *”think”* that your `/home` must be it’s own filesystem for you to be able to apply mount options, and that you cannot set mount options on subdirectories. - Then additionally people expect their home directory data to be persistent and you don’t create a tmpfs file system for that.

Comment: Can you also comment on what you're trying to protect? For instance, you can still run executables, even without the executable bit on a file.

Comment: @Halfgaar, I updated my post with a "goal" section to answer your question.

Comment: how should non root user be able to create block or dev devices?

Comment: @djdomi  I am actually just trying to achieve the fstab hardening advice mentioned in this very thorough server hardening guide https://linoxide.com/ultimate-guide-secure-ubuntu/  using a single partition instead of multiple.  This person who knows a lot more than me seems to think its a legitimate concern.

Comment: fstab can be used for partions not for subfolder. Thats a fact you cant change. and you can try to login to the system and try as user to create a dev it will mostly not possible

Comment: @djdomi, I don't question your expertise.  It's just that I got the first 3 fstab entries in my post to work / function as desired despite them not being separate partitions.  I was simply thrown when the 4th entry for /home had strange output.

Comment: the reason it works is that you use tmpfs ehich create a temporarily fs you vsn create nearly any folder with that but it will be gone after reboot. It doesnt change the requirements that /home must ve a separate partion that you can use fstab as already stated but not acceptable to your self ;)

Comment: Who said I didn't accept your explanation?  If you post an official answer, I'd gladly officially accept it..  ;-)  In any case, thx for the feedback, I will move to other problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mount options are set per file system (with the bind mount as the only "loophole" that I know of, as that uses an existing directory and mounts that as new separate file system )

A directory is NOT a partition/LVM volume/file system.

Therefor you can't use `/etc/fstab` or mount options on just your `/home directory.

If you have a business need for that, you'll need to migrate /home away from the root file system to its own partition/LVM volume/file system first.